# Rights (IAM) needed for GCP Cloud Datalab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to use Datalab in my customers GCP Account. What IAM Roles / Rights do I need to access it / create it / work with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/datalab-team), there are two ways to create VM instances for team members:

- A project owner can create instances for himself or other team members
- A project editor can create instances for himself (with some limitation)

If you can't get one of those two roles, you'll need to ask a project owner to create a Datalab instance on your behalf. To do this, the project owner will use the [`datalab create`](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/reference/command-line/create) command and pass in an additional `--for-user` flag specifying your email address.

In order to connect to your instance, you must have at least the following IAM roles:

- `roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1`
- `roles/iam.serviceAccountActor` for the service account attached to your Cloud Datalab instance

Comment: thank you :) I have seen that, but that is for teams. A single user datalab does need accees over service accounts normally. anny idea what the needed roles would be?

Comment: @LundinCast: the IAM role is now called `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`

Answer (score 0):

The role of `Editor` for a project should have the sufficient rights and permissions to launch and work with a Cloud Datalab instance.

On the customers GCP Account, also be sure to enable:

- Google Compute Engine API, and
- Cloud Source Repositories API from the **API and Services Library**.

Then you can launch a Datalab Instance from the **gcloud shell** or from the command-line on the local terminal assuming the Google Cloud SDK is installed by running the command:

```
datalab create [instance-name]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The customer is very careful with rights. What is the minimal roles that I need to use Datalab?
They wont give me the "Editor" role... :)

Comment: Try the `Compute Instance Admin` role, which gives permissions to create, modify, and delete virtual machine instances.

Comment: hey, we tried, but that was not it... Any more ideas?

Comment: Okay. Try creating a custom role to combine the `Compute Instance Admin` role with the `Source Repository Administrator` role. See https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/10/Introducing-custom-roles-a-powerful-way-to-make-Cloud-IAM-policies-more-precise.html for more help in doing this.